# Number of exercises and the learning of some subject?

Tags: mathematical-psychology, long-term-memory, mathematical-ability, short-term-memory

For example, I show to my students that X*Y=Z, so I ask for them to do some exercises, so in the future, they will always know that X*Y=Z.

Is there any known study relating the numbers of exercises needed to learn a subject?

And that relates the numbers of steps with the amount of practise?

Because we can see clearly that the sequency 1-3-8 is easier to remember than 1-3-8-6-9-8-7-5-5.

But the second sequency will need three more times of exercise to remember?

I think this may be useful in my studies, considering time a important factor.

If a do just some exercises, I just can half learn, and if I study much more than I need, I waste my time.

Answer (score 1):

Learning is a very complex process, do not expect to find precise answers like “5 exercises are required to learn a new subject”. There are many factors that affect learning, just to name a few:

- Your existing knowledge.
- Your engagement with the subject.
- How you learn. Deep Vs shallow processing.
- The complexity of the subject.
- Your personal characteristics e.g. IQ.
- Your current state, how much tired you are etc.

With so many factors involved is impossible to give precise answers.